# New User in SSMS Can't Login

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have installed SSMS (v17.1), created a new login at Security -> Logins, changed mode on the server (server: OWNER) to mixed mode.  But the username/password combination doesn't seem to work.  New Database Query -> SQL Server Authentication -> enter username/password and get error:  Cannot connect to OWNER. Login failed for user 'myusername'.  HELP!

Comment: Check sql server error log for the reason. It's written near to 18546 error Login failed for user...

Comment: I'm a bit new to using SSMS - could you tell me where to find the logs?  (or an instructional link)

Comment: exec xp_readerrorlog

Comment: Did you restart server after changing authentication mode? I guess the reason is your server is still using windows authentication only

Comment: I checked the logs as you instructed and found something interesting, even though I specified mixed mode: Login failed for user 'Enc'. Reason: An attempt to login using SQL authentication failed. Server is configured for Windows authentication only. [CLIENT: <local machine>]

Comment: Btw, is there a way to order the first column of the logs output descending?  It didn't like Order By.

Comment: That is what I wrote above. You should restart server in order the new configuration take place

Comment: You cannot use order by with stered procedure. You can create a table, insert rows from the log using INSERT dbo.t EXEC xp_readerrorlog and then select from dbo.t order by dt desc. But it's even more simple, you can open Management node in ssms, sql server logs, right click, view

Comment: The Management node method is great.  I think I see my mistake: I was restarting SSMS thinking that that was restarting the server but it was doing anything.  But now I see that I can right-click the server and properly attempt to restart it.  However, it won't let me restart it while in the Object Explorer, where I have to be to right-click it.  How can one restart the server from the Object Explorer, without getting the error that the it can't be restarted because the Object Explorer is a dependent service using it?

Comment: I don't understand what error you get, I can restart server from Object Explorer, anyway, you can restart it from Configuration Manager or from Services

Comment: I finally got it restarted.  I had to shutdown SQL Server Launchpad, SQL Server PolyBase Engine, and SQL Server PolyBase Data Movement, and then it would let me restart MSSQLSERVER in the Services.  I restarted SQL Server Launchpad, but SQL Server PolyBase Engine and Data Movement are stuck on Starting (actually, they were stuck on Starting even before I shut them down).  All that being said, the mixed mode seems to be working correctly now.  If you post this as a solution, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: Found the issue with the PolyBase items: TCP/IP had to be enabled in the configuration manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Change Server Authentication Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/change-server-authentication-mode) when the authentication mode is changed the server has to be restarted. Until restart SQL Server is still using Windows only authentication mode and that is what we can read is SQL Server error log as the reason of 18456 "login failed for user (...)"

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by following the instructions here: https://serverfault.com/questions/422269/where-can-i-find-the-user-in-this-iis-error-login-failed-for-user-iis-appool-w

All I did was create a user on the database, named IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool, and a login, also named IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool, using Windows authentication, and pointed the user at the login and it worked.  Frankly, I'm still not sure why my custom SQL Server user didn't work, but at least I can move forward with my project.